# Push Notification for iOS Device not working

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, aspnetcore-environment

I have a question for the push notification fcm for iOS device from server side ASPNetCore Web api.
When i send notification for the android device it was send successfully by using ServerKey and SenderID.
But when i send the push notification for the iOS Device i got error BadDeviceToken although when i using fcm which i received from the client and send directly from firebase console it's work but only from the server side i got BadDeviceToken.
Please can you tell me what is the problem is from server side?

```
      var apnSettings = new ApnSettings();
        apnSettings.ServerType = ApnServerType.Production;
        apnSettings.AppBundleIdentifier = _notificationSettings.AppBundleIdentifier;
        apnSettings.P8PrivateKey = _notificationSettings.P8PrivateKey;
        apnSettings.P8PrivateKeyId = _notificationSettings.P8PrivateKeyId;
        apnSettings.TeamId = _notificationSettings.TeamId;
```

**Using Core Push Lib**

thank you advance

Comment: send requests to `api.development.push.apple.com` instead of `api.push.apple.com`.  Change the `ApnServerType.Production` & let me know the response please.

Comment: Also the same when i changed the ApnServerType.Production to the Development => BadDeviceToken